# DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a property with the name 'Caption'

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I have in 1.xml file :

```
<Root>  
  <Node PCode="1" FieldName="FulName" Caption="F&LName" FieldValue="John Cary" FieldType="1" />
  <Node PCode="1" FieldName="Funct" Caption="MonthWork" FieldValue="29 days " FieldType="2" />
  <Node PCode="1" FieldName="FType" Caption="Work_Type" FieldValue="daily   " FieldType="2" />
  <Node PCode="1" FieldName="FTime" Caption="ExtraTime" FieldValue="0' : 90 " FieldType="2" />
  <Node PCode="1" FieldName="HTime" Caption="HolidTime" FieldValue="30' : 82" FieldType="2" />
</Root>
```

in C# behind code :

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(@"d:\1.xml");

DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

functionNodes.DataSource =  ds.Tables[0].Select("FieldType = '2'");
functionNodes.DataBind();
```

and in aspx file :

```
<asp:DataList ID="deductionsNodes" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label CssClass="itemTopics" runat="server" Text='<%# (Eval("FieldType").Equals("4")) ? Eval("Caption") : "" %>'></asp:Label>   **Error**
    <asp:Label CssClass="itemValues" runat="server" Text='<%# (Eval("FieldType").Equals("4")) ? Eval("FieldValue") : "" %>'></asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

when runtime, when cursor reach to run `DataBind()` method, this error occurs in first label tag in aspx code, and says :

> DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a property with the name 'Caption'.

I need to filter the rows with `FieldType=2` for using in DataList.

Note : when I delete the `.Select("FieldType = '2'")` method and use only `ds.Tables[0];` ,
       that returns all rows of all FieldTypes without any error, but returns all rows.

Comment: The aspx control you have listed is deductionsNodes but your code behind is referencing functionNodes?

Answer (score 0):

DataSource expects some form of DataView around the collection it is bound to. It appears that it is having difficulty being handed a raw array of DataRow.
One option is to use the DataTable's DefaultView and make use of the RowFilter functionality:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(@"d:\1.xml");
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "FieldType = '2'";

functionNodes.DataSource = dt;
functionNodes.DataBind();
```

I think the .aspx you posted is incorrect for the data binding, however. It only shows items of FieldType=4 while you're filtering on FieldType=2. This would always be empty.